# Image from database won't show up with php

Tags: php, mysql, database, image

I was trying to call some image in the div tag. All the other variables are showed up, but only the image won't show up. Can anyone point out the mistakes? Here's the code.

```
<div class="row">
        <?php
            include "config/database.php";
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM anidata";
            $query = mysql_query($sql);
            if ($query > 0){
        ?>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4" >
        <div class="thumbnail" >
            <?php
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
                    $image = $row['image'];
                    $title = $row['title'];
                    $genre = $row['genre'];
                    $start = $row['start'];
                    $schedule = $row['schedule'];
                    $description = $row['description'];
                }
            ?>
        <div>
          <img src="<?php echo $row["image"]; ?>" width="194" height="272">
        </div>

          <div class="caption">
            <span style="font-size:18px;"><?php echo $title; ?></span>
            <div class="line-title">
            </div>
            <div class="description">
                <span style="font-size:12px;"><?php echo $description; ?></span>
            </div>

            <div class="genre">
                <span><?php echo $genre; ?></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
      </div>
```

Comment: What does the rendered HTML output look like? Are the image paths correct?

Comment: `<img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" width="194" height="272">` - You're outside the loop using `$row["image"]`

Comment: Another useless comment ^^^ - Nobody hardly ever reads those anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do

```
 <img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" width="194" height="272">
```

Instead of "$row["image"]"

Comment: Thanks man, it's working perfectly now. need to wait 5 mins to accept your answer, i'll check it later. :)